# Angular 5 - Edit Array Function - How to

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an Angular 5 project and I have and Add and Remove function for an array.

See below:

```
addIT() {
    this.widgets.push({ id: 1, title: 'widget', config: { sizex: 1 } });
 }
```

What I finally need as an EDIT function so I can edit current array objects..

How do I do this?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to grab the element you want, and then make whatever modifications you need, like so:

```
editIT(id, prop, value) {
  var elem = this.widgets.find(elem => elem.id === id);
  if (elem !== null) {
    elem[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to make multiple edits at one time, you can pass in an object and use [`Object.prototype.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), like so:

```
editIT(id, changes) {
  var elem = this.widgets.find(elem => elem.id === id);
  if (elem !== null) {
    elem = Object.assign(elem, changes);
  }
}
```

To handle nested properties, you can use the following modification to the first solution above:

```
editIT(id, prop, value) {
    var elem = this.widgets.find(elem => elem.id === id);
    if (elem !== null) {
        var props = prop.split(".");
        // grab all except last property - we want the last property's containing object
        var propToEdit = props.slice(0, props.length-1).reduce(function (el, _prop) {
            // return nested object until last containing object
            return el[_prop];
        }, elem);
        // set value on last property's containing object to the value passed in
        propToEdit[props[props.length-1]] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I change the sizex property? Tired editIT(1, config.sizex, 2); but nothing happens

Comment: @max2020 Well, to do it right would involve quite a bit more code. However, you can do it quick and dirty as long as you pass a delimited string as your prop. I can edit the post accordingly.

Comment: @max2020 Updated: Check it out